# Assigning values if a string and a related int are equal

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the thing I'm having problems with..
I have a list of Strings, a list of Ints (both have the same length, the 2 lists are like "correlated" together).
I have to assign to the first pair (string and int) the value 0, then, if the next string is equal to one before and has the same correlated int, the value will be the same as the equal one befor, if one of them is different (or both obviously) I will assign the next higher value (if the last one was 2 the the  next one ofc will be 3)

```
EXAMPLE
[13,    14,     14,     8,        13,    13,    14,    14,    8,       13   ]
['pea', 'rpai', 'rpai', 'schiai', 'pea', 'rpe', 'zoi', 'zoi', 'briai', 'rpe']

values = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
"pea" on index 0 and index 4 have the same int, so they have the same value, same for the others
```

what is the most efficient way to correctly calculate the values whithout importing any external library?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Why the last value is 3?

Comment: Shouldn't the third `1` in the result be a `0`, since `(13, 'pea')` has been given the value `0`?  I.e. `[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]`.  It looks like the answer from @orlp makes the same correction.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Becasue `(13, 'rpe')` has been given the value `3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can combine your input into pairs using `zip`. And then repeatedly look up in a dictionary to see if the value exists yet, and if not assign the next biggest number. `d.setdefault(x, len(d))` where `d` is a dictionary does exactly that.

```
>>> ints = [13, 14, 14, 8, 13, 13, 14, 14, 8, 13]
>>> strs = ['pea', 'rpai', 'rpai', 'schiai', 'pea', 'rpe', 'zoi', 'zoi', 'briai', 'rpe']
>>> d = {}
>>> [d.setdefault(x, len(d)) for x in zip(ints, strs)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
```